# Writing a function to convert Two's Compliment to Base 10 in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary, converters, twos-complement

I am tasked with writing a function that takes a string of arbitrary length of Binary in the Two's Compliment system, and return the corresponding integer in base 10. I can not use for or while loops, and I can't use built in converting functions. I can use recursion.

I have written a helper function that takes the first digit in a string of binary and finds what value in base 10 this would add to the sum, I've copied it below.

```
def first(str):
    '''this program finds the value in base 10 of the 0th digit in a string of binary'''

    n=len(str)
    return int(str[0])*(2**(n-1))
```

I need help with the handling of negative numbers, as well as the formatting of the overall function.
Thanks!

Comment: This isn't a code-writing service; where is *your attempt*, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is an "I can haz teh codez plz" question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def bin(s):
    return 0 if not s else 2*bin(s[:-1]) + int(s[-1])

convert_2_to_decimal = lambda s: bin(s[1:]) - int(s[0])*2**(len(s)-1)
```